Calculating a billboard effect in an HLSL vertex shader in Unity
Imagine a volumetric point cloud, represented by a buffer of positions defining the location of each point. I'm generating a quad at each of those points, and my goal is to get the quads of each point to face the camera all the time. This billboard shader effect is a little bit more complex than your average quad because it uses Unity's procedural instancing feature, which allows the access to a buffer of vertex data.
I was able to get a solution that partially depends on a CSharp script for calculating, but I want to move all that calculating to a vertex shader.
Here's the working implementation I have:
// --------------------------
// My CSharp rendering script
// --------------------------

Update() {

    Vector3 cameraDirection =  (Camera.main.transform.position - elementTransform.position);
    Vector3 cameraNormalDirection = elementTransform.InverseTransformDirection(cameraDirection).normalized;
    
    // Calculate the object's new rotation to face towards the camera
    Vector3 forward = cameraNormalDirection;
    Vector3 referenceUp = Vector3.up;
                
    // Use 'Right' as the referenced 'Up' vector if the forward is almost paralell to 'Up' 
    if (Mathf.Abs(Vector3.Dot(forward, referenceUp)) > 0.99f) {
        referenceUp = Vector3.right;
    }
                
    Vector3 right = Vector3.Cross(referenceUp, forward).normalized;
    Vector3 up = Vector3.Cross(forward, right);
    
    // Euler(180, 0, 0) is simply an offset to help orient the vertices.
    Quaternion lookRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(forward, up) * Quaternion.Euler(180, 0, 0);
    
    material.SetMatrix("_localQuaternion", Matrix4x4.TRS(Vector3.zero, lookRotation, Vector3.one));
}
    
// --------------------------
// My HLSL shader
// --------------------------
float4x4 _localQuaternion;  // ...and more!

void ConfigureProcedural()
{ //run per vertex
#if defined(UNITY_PROCEDURAL_INSTANCING_ENABLED)

    float3 position = _Positions[unity_InstanceID];

    float4x4 scale = {  
        _Step,0.0,0.0,0.0,
        0.0,_Step,0.0,0.0,
    0.0,0.0,_Step,0.0,
    0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0 };

    float4x4 worldPos = {
        1.0,0.0,0.0,(position.x * _scale)+_worldPos.x,
        0.0,1.0,0.0,(position.y * _scale)+_worldPos.y,
    0.0,0.0,1.0,(position.z * _scale)+ _worldPos.z,
    0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0 };

    float4x4 localPos = {
        1.0,0.0,0.0,position.x * _scale,
        0.0,1.0,0.0,position.y * _scale,
    0.0,0.0,1.0, position.z * _scale,
        0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0 };
    
    float4x4 localPosNegative = {
        1.0,0.0,0.0,- position.x * _scale,
    0.0,1.0,0.0,- position.y * _scale,
    0.0,0.0,1.0,- position.z * _scale,
    0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0 };

unity_ObjectToWorld = mul(mul(mul(mul(mul(worldPos,localPosNegative), _quaternion), localPos), scale), _localQuaternion);

The HLSL shader is adapted from Ahmad Efani's point cloud tutorial: https://medium.com/design-bootcamp/point-cloud-rendering-with-unity-1a07345eb27a
In the above working implementation, notice that I'm calculating a localQuaternion in the CS script, which contains the rotation to face the quads at the camera. Then, in the shader, I multiply it at the right-most side, and it successfully gets applied to the vertex at its origin.
Now, I'm trying to move those calculations to the shader. Unsuccessfully, the point cloud appears to only point in one direction, which I tested by moving the camera around it and rotating the object.
When I rotate the object, it looks like the billboard rotates along with it, and does not re-orient to face the camera.
Here's my non-working implementation:
// --------------------------
// My CSharp rendering script
// --------------------------

// I just pass in the camera's position
material.SetVector("_targetPosition", Camera.main.transform.position);

// --------------------------
// My HLSL shader
// --------------------------
float3 _targetPosition; // World space

void ConfigureProcedural()
{ //run per vertex
#if defined(UNITY_PROCEDURAL_INSTANCING_ENABLED)

    // The matrices mentioned earlier, plus another

    float4x4 worldPosNegative = { // world to local space
        1.0,0.0,0.0,(-position.x * _scale) - _worldPos.x,  
        0.0,1.0,0.0,(-position.y * _scale) - _worldPos.y,                
        0.0,0.0,1.0,(-position.z * _scale) - _worldPos.z,                
        0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0 };

    float4x4 rotateX180 = {
        1.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,
        0.0,-1.0,0.0, 0.0,
        0.0,0.0,-1.0, 0.0,
        0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 };

    // Get the worldPos of vertex to compute its direction vection with the target
    float3 wPos = mul(worldPos, float4(0, 0, 0, 1)).xyz;

    // Construct the rotation matrix for aligning vertices to face the target
    float3 targetDir = _targetPosition - wPos;  
    float3 forward = normalize(mul(worldPosNegative, float4(targetDir, 0)).xyz);
    float3 up = float3(0, 1, 0);
    float3 right = normalize(cross(up, forward));
    up = normalize(cross(forward, right));

    float4x4 rotationMatrix = float4x4(
        float4(right, 0),
        float4(up, 0),
        float4(-forward, 0),  // Negative forward to face the camera
        float4(0, 0, 0, 1)
    );

    rotationMatrix = mul(rotationMatrix, rotateX180);

    unity_ObjectToWorld = mul(mul(mul(mul(mul(worldPos,localPosNegative), _quaternion), localPos), scale), rotationMatrix);
}

